# .NET/C# to MySql running on linux - exception on first command, but subsequent commands do work

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Have a really crazy situation.  I can't post specifics, so I'm just looking for general guidance.  We have already opened a ticket with Oracle/MySql support.  I'm just looking to see if anyone else has run into this situation or anything similar.  Here is our scenario:

- Windows 2012 R2 Server with .NET 4.7.1 running.
- Simple Windows Forms .NET application.
- We are trying to run a simple query against a Linux MySql Server. MySql is Enterprise Version 5.7.x.
- On the first attempted connection, the Windows Forms app locks the UI, waits about 15 seconds, and then reports back that there is an error running the command.  The error is shown below.

System.ApplicationException: An exception occurred on the following sql command:select * from tablename where compl_date >= '2019-12-17 04:44:34 PM' ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host 'ip address' for user 'userid' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

- When this error pops up, if I click on the "Continue" button, subsequent calls to the database work as intended (at about a 95% rate).
- On the server, the mysqld error logs are shown below for the first call.  Subsequent calls do work.

  2019-12-16T22:06:29.554171Z 3496 [Warning] IP address 'client ip address' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
  2019-12-16T22:06:50.188443Z 3496 [Note] Aborted connection 3496 to db: 'drupaldb' user: 'userid' host: 'ip address' (Got an error reading communication packets)
  2019-12-17T02:53:17.832725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 11355ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
  2019-12-17T03:25:18.200855Z 3527 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
  2019-12-17T03:25:37.167395Z 3528 [Note] Got packets out of order
  2019-12-17T03:25:37.382512Z 3529 [Note] Got packets out of order
  2019-12-17T03:25:47.688836Z 3530 [Note] Bad handshake
  2019-12-17T14:26:33.619967Z 4803 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets
  2019-12-17T19:34:34.741441Z 4851 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets
  2019-12-17T19:47:47.595426Z 4853 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets
  2019-12-17T19:48:45.586357Z 4854 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets

If you have some general ideas, let me know.

- FYI, we have some other linux/mysql instances, and this runs just fine.

Comment: It might be due to the reverse DNS lookup done by the MySql server being slow, you could add `skip-name-resolve` to the MySql config to test that. There could also be some network/firewall issue between the client and the server, as they both seem to suggest they loose the connection. Perhaps see if other types of connections between that client and that server are stable.

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: This definitely seems like a configuration or networking (or possibly even a hardware) issue. Google suggests configuration: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets

Answer (score 0):

At this point, we think we have solved the problem, at least for the short term.  Both server and client are sitting on a private network.  We think that the database server is trying to send a certificate to the windows client.  The windows client is also on this private network.  We think the Windows Client is not accepting the ssl certificate and that this is causing the failure on the first connection attempt.  By adding the option "SslMode=None", this seems to resolve the issue.

Blog post we found that helped us: https://blog.csdn.net/fancyf/article/details/78295964